# How can I limit a page to where the footer is, even if the footer is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I am trying to use these "Pure CSS Parallax Pixel Stars" which are from this github : [Github Here](https://gist.github.com/CodeMyUI/ffc4a16172b7910a61d1)

My problem is that on one of the pages that it is on, I cannot set the height because it is a dynamic page based on what the user clicks. I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to fix this so that the stars do not go below the footer. I'm open to JavaScript options as well, but I would like a different take on this issue.